# Implement gridview in Viewflipper

Tags: android

I have custom gridview with icon & text, gridview is displayed in 2 columns

now i want to implement it using viewflipeer

i.e every time I fling, it has to display a cell each time.
when i fling to left, it has to show left cell item, like wise left,right, top, bottom

can any body help??

Thanx in advance

Chiranjeevi

Comment: can somebody please respond!!, it's urgent please..

Comment: did u solved this problem . if yes can you say how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is having a scrollable to detect a fling.

Look here for the problem:
[Swipe/Fling tab-changing in conjunction with ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102993/swipe-fling-tab-changing-in-conjunction-with-scrollview)

try out this solution :
http://www.jmstudio.org/archives/391