# ListActivity inside TabActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, gestures, tabactivity, onfling

Please help to solve this problem.
I use implementation of OnGestureListener in TabActivity with overriding of method onFling for switching between tabs. But that doesn't work when one of my tabs is ListActivity. 
Thanks

Comment: Your ListActivity has a ListView I imagine? It sounds like the same problem I have here with ScrollView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102993/swipe-fling-tab-changing-in-conjunction-with-scrollview The ListView also listens for onTouchEvent which gives some issues. ListView.java: http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java&d=3

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the listener to ListView or yours ListActivity too.